# openCV video saving in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save the video but it's not working.
I followed the instructions from the openCV documentation.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)


        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()

out.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What is wrong?

Comment: It works fine with my computer. In fact the accepted answer doesnt work

Comment: Make sure the directory you are trying to write to exists, otherwise it will fail silently.

Comment: On my system, only 'DIVX' works whereas the encoding given included on the opencv documentation examples, namely 'M', 'J', 'P', 'G', just silently writes no file. I wish there was a way to verify the codec so that my code is more safely portable with regard to codec availability.

Comment: This code works fine for me.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this. It's working for me (Windows 10).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
#fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'DIVX')
#out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', -1, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It isn't work for me. Create only a empty video file (with size 5,6 kB).

Comment: For those who cannot generate videos, please change the fourcc param

Comment: It is not creating output.avi file

Comment: The code snippet in the question works perfectly fine

Comment: indeed the code snippet in the question works fine but this answer does not. Is it OS dependent? I'm on ubuntu.

Comment: This answer should work on windows properly as said in this [fourcc = -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998799/specify-compression-quality-in-python-for-opencv-video-object) as a windows dialogue for compression quality will open up, and also, this code doesn't work for me on ubuntu, doesn't even create an empty **output.avi** file . Also, the code snippet in the question doesn't work for me, it seems as given in the below answers: *one has to use the same frame width and height as in the input video/image.*

Answer (score 32):

jveitchmichaelis at https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/223 provided a thorough answer. Here I copied his answer:

> The documentation in OpenCV says (hidden away) that you can only write
>   to avi using OpenCV3. Whether that's true or not I've not been able to
>   determine, but I've been unable to write to anything else.
>
> However, OpenCV is mainly a computer vision library, not a video stream, codec and write one. Therefore, the developers tried to keep
>   this part as simple as possible. Due to this OpenCV for video
>   containers supports only the avi extension, its first version.
>
> From: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d9e/tutorial_video_write.html
>
> My setup: I built OpenCV 3 from source using MSVC 2015, including
>   ffmpeg. I've also downloaded and installed XVID and openh264 from
>   Cisco, which I added to my PATH. I'm running Anaconda Python 3. I also
>   downloaded a recent build of ffmpeg and added the bin folder to my
>   path, though that shouldn't make a difference as its baked into
>   OpenCV.
>
> I'm running in Win 10 64-bit.
>
> This code seems to work fine on my computer. It will generate a video
>   containing random static:
>
> ```
> writer = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi",
> cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG"), 30,(640,480))
>
> for frame in range(1000):
>     writer.write(np.random.randint(0, 255, (480,640,3)).astype('uint8'))
>
> writer.release()
> ```
>
> Some things I've learned through trial and error:
>
> - Only use '.avi', it's just a container, the codec is the important thing.
> - Be careful with specifying frame sizes. In the constructor you need to pass the frame size as (column, row) e.g. 640x480. However the
>     array you pass in, is indexed as (row, column). See in the above
>     example how it's switched?
> - If your input image has a different size to the VideoWriter, it will fail (often silently)
> - Only pass in 8 bit images, manually cast your arrays if you have to (.astype('uint8'))
> - In fact, never mind, just always cast. Even if you load in images using cv2.imread, you need to cast to uint8...
> - MJPG will fail if you don't pass in a 3 channel, 8-bit image. I get an assertion failure for this at least.
> - XVID also requires a 3 channel image but fails silently if you don't do this.
> - H264 seems to be fine with a single channel image
> - If you need raw output, say from a machine vision camera, you can use 'DIB '. 'RAW ' or an empty codec sometimes works. Oddly if I use
>     DIB, I get an ffmpeg error, but the video is saved fine. If I use RAW,
>     there isn't an error, but Windows Video player won't open it. All are
>     fine in VLC.
>
> In the end I think the key point is that OpenCV is not designed to be
>   a video capture library - it doesn't even support sound. VideoWriter
>   is useful, but 99% of the time you're better off saving all your
>   images into a folder and using ffmpeg to turn them into a useful
>   video.

Comment: "(column, row) e.g. 640x480. However the array you pass in, is indexed as (row, column)" I lost 1 day of work because of this. Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

In my case, I found that size of Writer have to matched with the frame size both from camera or files. So that I read the frame size first and apply to writer setting as below.

```
(grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
fshape = frame.shape
fheight = fshape[0]
fwidth = fshape[1]
print fwidth , fheight
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (fwidth,fheight))
```

Comment: camera is not defined, what is camera?

Comment: @nycynik if you are working with a camera directly instead of a saved video

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Either OpenCV has changed, or everyone else seems to have 640x480 webcams.

Answer (score 18):

You need to get the exact size of the capture like this:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) + 0.5)
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) + 0.5)
size = (width, height)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('your_video.avi', fourcc, 20.0, size)

while(True):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Recording...', frame)
    out.write(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you it worked for me! but can you tell me why exactly we need the "exact" size?

Comment: @Mayan Exact size in the sense of original video frame width and height.

Comment: this worked for me on window 10, python 3.7

Comment: What's the significance of the `+ 0.5`?

Comment: Can confirm this works without +0.5 as well. good answer.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 23.10.

Answer (score 8):

I also faced same problem but it worked when I used ***'MJPG'*** instead of **'XVID'**

I used

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
```

instead of

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
```

Answer (score 8):

Please make sure to set correct width and height. You can set it like bellow

```
cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (int(cap.get(3)), int(cap.get(4))))
```

Answer (score 6):

This answer covers what's what in terms of variables and importantly, output size shall be same for input frame and video size.

```
import cv2

save_name = "output.mp4"
fps = 10
width = 600
height = 480
output_size = (width, height)
out = cv2.VideoWriter(save_name,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), fps , output_size )

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # 0 for webcam or you can put in videopath
while(True):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Video Frame', frame)
    out.write(cv2.resize(frame, output_size ))
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer was only tested in MacOS but it will probably also work in Linux and Windows.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Get the Default resolutions
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

# Define the codec and filename.
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 10, (frame_width,frame_height))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:

        # write the  frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This does work, but my **input video file was 83MB**, but I end up getting **output.avi of near 1Gigabytes size**. *Can you please explain as to why this might be happening and how to rectify this?* Also, why do I need to use the same `height` and `width`?

Answer (score 3):

The other answers work for saving a **single** video feed. But if you have more then one video source, say numerous IP camera feeds, RTSP streams, or webcams, you may want to record them all at once. Here's a method for saving **multiple** video feeds simultaneously using multithreading. The idea is to have two threads for each video source: 1) dedicated to only reading frames from the stream and 2) dedicated for processing frames (showing and saving).

Since `cv2.VideoCapture.read()` is a blocking operation, we must separate reading frames from saving frames. We can read frames in its own independent thread to improve performance by reducing latency due to I/O operations. By dedicating frame capture to its own thread, there will always be a frame ready to be processed instead of having to wait for the I/O operation to complete and return a fresh frame. The second thread is dedicated to processing and saving frames to the output file. We can encapsulate all of this into a single object, where it can be scaled regardless of the number of simultaneous video streams. Be sure to change the video `src` parameter to your own video source. Here's an example of simultaneously recording three video streams.

[image]

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2
import time

class VideoWriterWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, video_file_name, src=0):
        # Create a VideoCapture object
        self.frame_name = str(src)
        self.video_file = video_file_name
        self.video_file_name = video_file_name + '.avi'
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)

        # Default resolutions of the frame are obtained (system dependent)
        self.frame_width = int(self.capture.get(3))
        self.frame_height = int(self.capture.get(4))

        # Set up codec and output video settings
        self.codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
        self.output_video = cv2.VideoWriter(self.video_file_name, self.codec, 30, (self.frame_width, self.frame_height))

        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()
        
        # Start another thread to show/save frames
        self.start_recording()
        print('initialized {}'.format(self.video_file))

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()

    def show_frame(self):
        # Display frames in main program
        if self.status:
            cv2.imshow(self.frame_name, self.frame)

        # Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            self.output_video.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)

    def save_frame(self):
        # Save obtained frame into video output file
        self.output_video.write(self.frame)
    
    def start_recording(self):
        # Create another thread to show/save frames
        def start_recording_thread():
            while True:
                try:
                    self.show_frame()
                    self.save_frame()
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
        self.recording_thread = Thread(target=start_recording_thread, args=())
        self.recording_thread.daemon = True
        self.recording_thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    src1 = 'Your link1'
    video_writer_widget1 = VideoWriterWidget('Camera 1', src1)
    src2 = 'Your link2'
    video_writer_widget2 = VideoWriterWidget('Camera 2', src2)
    src3 = 'Your link3'
    video_writer_widget3 = VideoWriterWidget('Camera 3', src3)
        
    # Since each video player is in its own thread, we need to keep the main thread alive.
    # Keep spinning using time.sleep() so the background threads keep running
    # Threads are set to daemon=True so they will automatically die 
    # when the main thread dies
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
```

---

Related camera/IP/RTSP/streaming, FPS, video, threading, and multiprocessing posts

1. [Python OpenCV streaming from camera - multithreading, timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55099413/python-opencv-streaming-from-camera-multithreading-timestamps)
2. [Video Streaming from IP Camera in Python Using OpenCV cv2.VideoCapture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828451/video-streaming-from-ip-camera-in-python-using-opencv-cv2-videocapture)
3. [How to capture multiple camera streams with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592291/how-to-capture-multiple-camera-streams-with-opencv)
4. [OpenCV real time streaming video capture is slow. How to drop frames or get synced with real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293187/opencv-real-time-streaming-video-capture-is-slow-how-to-drop-frames-or-get-sync)
5. [Storing RTSP stream as video file with OpenCV VideoWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141315/storing-rtsp-stream-as-video-file-with-opencv-videowriter)
6. [OpenCV video saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317262/opencv-video-saving-in-python/71624807#71624807)
7. [Python OpenCV multiprocessing cv2.VideoCapture mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72120491/python-opencv-multiprocessing-cv2-videocapture-mp4)

Comment: your solutions offers an alternative approach. thanks for posting the idea

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and then I tried this:

```
frame = cv2.flip(frame,180)
```

instead of

```
frame= cv2.flip(frame,0)
```

and it's working.

Comment: just remove that line if you dont want to flip the image, it's not required.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't having codec issues or dimension issues as the answers above. Instead, my issue was because my output frames were in greyscale.

I had to create a VideoWriter with the parameter isColor=False

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_path,
                      cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'),
                      30,
                      (INPUT_VIDEO_WIDTH,INPUT_VIDEO_HEIGHT),
                      isColor=False
                      )
```

In the [API Docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html), it **wrongly** says that the flag is currently supported on Windows only. I have tested on Ubuntu 20.04, with opencv-python==4.2.0.34, and it finally writes out to file correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Nuru answer actually works, only thing is remove this line `frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)` under  `if ret==True:` loop which will output the video file without flipping

Answer (score 1):

As an example :

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out_corner = cv2.VideoWriter('img_corner_1.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))
```

At that place, have to define X,Y as width and height

But, when you create an image (a blank image for instance) you have to define Y,X as height and width :

```
    img_corner = np.zeros((480, 640, 3), np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm Kind of late, But [**`VidGear`**](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear) Python Library's [WriteGear  API](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/writegear/introduction/) **automates the process of pipelining OpenCV frames into FFmpeg on any platform in real-time with [Hardware Encoders support](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/writegear/compression/usage/#using-compression-mode-with-hardware-encoders)** and *at the same time provides same opencv-python syntax*. Here's a basic python example:

```py
# import libraries
from vidgear.gears import WriteGear
import cv2

output_params = {"-vcodec":"libx264", "-crf": 0, "-preset": "fast"} #define (Codec,CRF,preset) FFmpeg tweak parameters for writer

stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #Open live webcam video stream on first index(i.e. 0) device

writer = WriteGear(output_filename = 'Output.mp4', compression_mode = True, logging = True, **output_params) #Define writer with output filename 'Output.mp4' 

# infinite loop
while True:
    
    (grabbed, frame) = stream.read()
    # read frames

    # check if frame empty
    if not is grabbed:
        #if True break the infinite loop
        break
    

    # {do something with frame here}
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # write a modified frame to writer
    writer.write(gray) 
       
    # Show output window
    cv2.imshow("Output Frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # check for 'q' key-press
    if key == ord("q"):
        #if 'q' key-pressed break out
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# close output window

stream.release()
# safely close video stream
writer.close()
# safely close writer
```

Source:https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/writegear/compression/usage/#using-compression-mode-with-opencv

You can check out [VidGear Docs](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear) for more advanced applications and features.

Answer (score 0):

As @ปรีดา ตั้งนภากร said: the sizes of Writer have to match with the frame from the camera or files.

You can use such code to check if your camera is (640, 480) or not:

```
print(int(cap.get(3)), int(cap.get(4)))
```

For myself, I found my camera is (1280, 720) and replaced (640, 480) with (1280, 720). Then it can save videos.

Comment: Who are you trying to reference? For me it says you're crediting `@ปรีดา ตั้งนภากร` which doesn't appear to be anyone in this thread.

Comment: ปรีดา ตั้งนภากร is one of the guys answering this question. You can find/search him in this thread/page.
Maybe it is better to find the official explanation for it.

Comment: Ah disregard, you're right. For some reason his answer didn't appear at all for me.

Comment: For the curious, those squiggly things (Thai) are pronounced as "Prida Tangnaphakorn"!  :P

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D')
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, 20,(frame_width,frame_height),True )
print(int(cap.get(3)))
print(int(cap.get(4)))
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        print(frame.shape)
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
out.release()`enter code here`

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This works fine but the problem of having video size relatively very small means nothing is captured. So make sure the height and width of a video and the image that you are going to recorded is same. If you are using some manipulation after capturing a video than you must confirm the size (before and after). 
Hope it will save some1's hour

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write a grayscale image and nothing worked for me, I had to add a **0** to VideoWriter

`out = cv2.VideoWriter(outfilename, fourcc, fps, (width, height), 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the width and the height of the video according to the size of the image feed. Otherwise, it will create a file size of around 5.5KB.

```
result = cv2.VideoWriter(name,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'), 10, (**960, 540**))
```