# OpenCV (3.1.0) video saving in Python (3.5.1) on Mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv, video

I am following the OpenCV documentation on video saving using the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
height = int(cap.get(4))
width = int(cap.get(3))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (width, height))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)


        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run it, it works fine but the video file saved can't be opened by VLC/quick time etc.

From [openCV video saving in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317262/opencv-video-saving-in-python?newreg=04b534641772453abcadd398336fb563) i've noticed you can change  fourcc to -1 allowing you to pick your codec if you are on a windows machine. But I can't do this on a Mac (OSX 10.11.12).

I have also tried a bunch of other fourcc options, but none seem to work on Mac.

Any suggestions?