# CPU is 100% for multiprocessing queue to get frames from multiple cameras

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, image-processing, multiprocessing

I am working on an image-processing project where I want pictures from 3 cameras to get the latest frame when a button is pressed and for that, I have used multiprocessing.process and multiprocessing.queue as shown in the code below. The required task is achieved but there are 2 problems right now:

1.cpu-100% in task manager(which slows down the program)

2.there is a workaround for cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 0) in the code which is the main cause for 50% of cpu usage

actually I want a fast way to get frames so I have also tried multiprocessing.pipe instead of the queue but since it does not get the latest frame when button pressed for the second time so I had to use queu communication method. Any help regarding code would be much appreciated

```
def camera_func(queue,cam_indx):
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_indx,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)   #current camera
    cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 0)
    if cam.isOpened(): # Check success if the object is created and opened                    
        while True:
            try:
                flag, frame=cam.read()
                if flag==0:
                    break 
                # used to remove buffer size problem because it gets next frame 
                # rather latest frame   
                if not queue.empty():
                    try:
                        queue.get_nowait()   # discard previous (unprocessed) frame
                    except Queue.Empty:
                        pass

                queue.put(frame,False)

            except:
                continue      
    else:               
        cam.open()        
        raise Exception("Could not open camera")

queues=[]
for pip in range(0,a_cams):
    queu = Queue(maxsize=1)
    queues.append(queu)

processes = [Process(target=camera_func, args=(queues[x],x)) for x in range(a_cams)]   # Setup a list of processes that we want to run
for p in processes:     
    p.start()   # Run processes
```

**Update:**

I have used threading as suggested by nathancy and now it is doing the same task without the workaround thanks to fps sync from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293187/opencv-real-time-streaming-video-capture-is-slow-how-to-drop-frames-or-get-sync/58386085), and CPU usage is still 80% but this time there is 40-sec lag when starting the program which is too much.

Comment: Have you done any benchmarking/profiling?

Comment: does it behave linearly? e.g. 40% vcpu usage for 1 camera, 80% for 2, 100% for 3? Do you have a multicore system a d could go beyond 100% if multie threads were used?

Comment: how do one do benchmark profiling?

Comment: no it does not behave linearly 50% usage when no workaround i.e. i get consective frame not latest when button was pressed. where as 50% jumps in when i do the workaround. I have i7 8gen 12core system

Comment: no, I haven't tried threading because I have 3 separate cameras

Comment: You can put each camera into a separate thread, I use this technique with about 9 IP cameras

Comment: I am trying threading but I get error, may be I am doing wrong, can you share some simple code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May someone find it useful!

Since nobody answered my question so trying everything that I can I found that only changing the `capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)` line in the threaded version of the camera input to `capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)` significantly reduces the CPU usage plus there is no lag in the start also.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I found that it was directly related to how I was checking the queue.

I also had

```
if not queue.empty():
    try:
        r = queue.get()
        ...
```

What reduced the cpu load to near zero was removing the .empty() check. The .get() call automatically waits for something to be present in the queue before it continues.