Cannot use OpenCV read four 1080p cameras simultaneously
When I run the following code, all four cameras can be turned on (openCamera() does not return -1), but at most only two cameras can output images, and more precisely, they all work at low frame rates of 1080p, which means setting frame rates is useless.
Here is my test code
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf8

import cv2
import time
def openCamera(cam_index = 0):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_index)

    if cap.isOpened():
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920) #1
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080) #2
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30) #3
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'))
        return cap
    else:
        print(str(cam_index) + "launch failed")
        return -1
        
cam_set = []

for i in range(0,8,2): #4
    temp = openCamera(i)
    if temp != -1:
        cam_set.append(temp) 
print("have ", len(cam_set),"cams running")

while(cam_set):
    window_cnt = 0
    for k in cam_set:
        
        cap = k
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow(str(window_cnt+1), frame)
            window_cnt += 1
            cv2.waitKey(1)
else:
    print("camera launched failed")

for j in cam_set:
    j.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

My four cameras are connected to the Orin NX,which has four USB 3.0 interfaces, so it cannot be a power or bandwidth issue.
Attempted solutions:
When Cap.set (cv2.CAP-PROP-FRAME.WIDTH, 1920) # 1  Cap.set (cv2.CAP-PROP-FRAME-HEIGHT, 1080) # 2 are commented out, all four cameras can output the image, but it is still abnormal. It runs at a resolution of 640 * 480 at 30 fps.
I tried to turn on each camera separately, each camera could run at 1080p 30fps.
So I really want to know how to make all four cameras run simultaneously at 1080p and 30fps,this is just a test program. Ultimately, this feature will be implemented in a four threaded C++ program, allowing each thread to read a camera image
-----------Off topic remarks-----------
I am also a Linux novice, I don't know why there are only four cameras, but when I run ls /dev/video*, it shows
/dev/video0  /dev/video2  /dev/video4  /dev/video6
/dev/video1  /dev/video3  /dev/video5  /dev/video7

this is also why I write for i in range(0,8,2): #4 .
Did someone know this?

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/q/58592291/18667225

You should know that having four USB 3.0 connectors does not mean that you have four full speed USB 3.0 connections. It does not even mean that USB 3.0 is used. Most cameras use USB 2.0 and they are connected over a root hub, then their combined bandwidth is limited to 480 Mbit/s in theory and even less in practice. Check lsusb -t for details.

check to make sure the MJPG actually takes effect. order of set() calls matters. it might need to be first, last, or in whatever other position.

You are running the cameras sequentially - consider using threading to run them all simultaneously.
