# How to run OpenCV VideoCapture's read function outside multithreading class?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, opencv, python-multithreading, video-capture

I am using [Nathancy's SO code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55099413/python-opencv-streaming-from-camera-multithreading-timestamps/55131226) to read two static videos from disk in parallel, leveraging multithreading. The below modified code works perfectly fine for me:

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2, time


class VideoStreamWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.image) = self.capture.read()
                self.frame = cv2.resize(self.image, (640, 480))
            time.sleep(.01)

    def show_frame(self, win_name='frame_1'):
        # Display frames in main program
        cv2.imshow(win_name, self.frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_stream_widget1 = VideoStreamWidget(src=r'C:\Users\ab\Documents\Video\ch6.asf')
    video_stream_widget2 = VideoStreamWidget(
        src=r'C:\Users\ab\Documents\Video\ch4.asf')
    while True:
        try:
            video_stream_widget1.show_frame('frame_1')
            video_stream_widget2.show_frame('frame_2')
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Now I'm trying to tweak through the above code as I want to create a while loop outside the class and get status and image from capture.read() function to be used by other codes in a loop, frame by frame. But, it is not working for even single video stream with this (Assertion fctx->async_lock failed at libavcodec/pthread_frame.c:155) error. Code is as follows:

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2, time


class VideoStreamWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.image) = self.capture.read()
                self.frame = cv2.resize(self.image, (640, 480))
            # time.sleep(.01)

    # def show_frame(self, win_name='frame_1'):
    #     # Display frames in main program
    #     cv2.imshow(win_name, self.frame)
    #     key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    #     if key == ord('q'):
    #         self.capture.release()
    #         cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    #         exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_stream_widget1 = VideoStreamWidget(src=r'C:\Users\ab\Documents\Video\ch6.asf')
    # video_stream_widget2 = VideoStreamWidget(
    #     src=r'C:\Users\ab\Documents\Video\ch4.asf')
    # while True:
    #     try:
    #         video_stream_widget1.show_frame('frame_1')
    #         video_stream_widget2.show_frame('frame_2')
    #     except AttributeError:
    #         pass
    while True:
        vflag, image_np = video_stream_widget1.status, video_stream_widget1.frame
        print(image_np)
```

Is it a setter getter problem? Can you help point out where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After trying out couple of ways, adding the self.status, self.image and self.frame in the **init** solved the problem. Since it is multi-threaded, we need to explicitly init these variables in the constructor.