# Python OpenCV multiprocessing cv2.VideoCapture mp4

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video, multiprocessing

I want to run some `mp4` videos inside a process but only camera feed works. The software gets stuck with no error message. I already tried both and I found this doesn't run. The print is where the code gets stuck.

```
import cv2
import multiprocessing

dispW=640
dispH=480

# Camera inputs 

cap=cv2.VideoCapture('/home/kc/Downloads/darknet/1.mp4')
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, dispW)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, dispH)

#cv2.namedWindow("Window")

def c1():
    global cap
    while True:
        print('here')
        success, img = cap.read()
        #ret, frame1 = cap1.read()
        #frame2 = numpy.hstack((frame,frame1))
        print('here')
        cv2.imshow("Window2", img)

        #This breaks on 'q' key
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

tCap1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=c1)
tCap1.start()
```

this runs.

```
import cv2
import multiprocessing

dispW=640
dispH=480

# Camera inputs 

cap=cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0')
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, dispW)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, dispH)


#cv2.namedWindow("Window")
def c1():
    global cap
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        #ret, frame1 = cap1.read()
        #frame2 = numpy.hstack((frame,frame1))
        print('here')
        cv2.imshow("Window2", img)

        #This breaks on 'q' key
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

tCap1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=c1)
tCap1.start()
```

I need an example of mp4 file run in a multiprocessing way.

Comment: you **can't set** the width/height of a video that you **read** -- always check: `assert cap.isOpened()` once after creating the VideoCapture object

Comment: code works for me (on Linux Mint) if I create `cap` inside function. Multiprocesses don't share memory so creating `cap` in main process and later use `global` is not good idea. Other problem is that when it creates new process then main thread saves all in file using pickle and new thread has to read it - and for file it may not work as expected.

Comment: Code works for me using raspberry pi 4 (linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal working example with optional FPS control. If you need to extract frames from your process back to the main program, you can use [`multiprocessing.Queue()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) to transfer frames since multiprocesses have an independent memory stack.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import cv2, time

def capture_frames():
    src = 'test.mp4'
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 2)

    # FPS = 1/X, X = desired FPS
    FPS = 1/120
    FPS_MS = int(FPS * 1000)

    while True:
        # Ensure camera is connected
        if capture.isOpened():
            (status, frame) = capture.read()
            
            # Ensure valid frame
            if status:
                cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            else:
                break
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
            time.sleep(FPS)

    capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting video stream')
    capture_process = mp.Process(target=capture_frames, args=())
    capture_process.start()
```

---

Related camera/IP/RTSP/streaming, FPS, video, threading, and multiprocessing posts

1. [Python OpenCV streaming from camera - multithreading, timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55099413/python-opencv-streaming-from-camera-multithreading-timestamps)
2. [Video Streaming from IP Camera in Python Using OpenCV cv2.VideoCapture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828451/video-streaming-from-ip-camera-in-python-using-opencv-cv2-videocapture)
3. [How to capture multiple camera streams with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592291/how-to-capture-multiple-camera-streams-with-opencv)
4. [OpenCV real time streaming video capture is slow. How to drop frames or get synced with real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293187/opencv-real-time-streaming-video-capture-is-slow-how-to-drop-frames-or-get-sync)
5. [Storing RTSP stream as video file with OpenCV VideoWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141315/storing-rtsp-stream-as-video-file-with-opencv-videowriter)
6. [OpenCV video saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317262/opencv-video-saving-in-python/71624807#71624807)
7. [Python OpenCV multiprocessing cv2.VideoCapture mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72120491/python-opencv-multiprocessing-cv2-videocapture-mp4)