# How to save the capture image file in USB using python opencv function named "imwrite" in Linux

Tags: python, opencv, usb

I tried to save capture of webcam image in USB using Python on Linux environment.

"Imwrite" is work in file directory but not work in USB directory.

I tried on 'os' package and path.

Is there other method to doing this?

```
path='/media/odroid/MYUSB/savefolder/'
capture_img=/demo/capture.jpg
image=cv2.imread(capture_img)
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, resave.jpg),image)
```

The whole code is running without error, but jpg file is not saved in MYUSB

Comment: Im very sure your code will not run without error but raise a SyntaxError in the 2nd line.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't need to use `os.join()` try this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
savePath = 'output.jpg' #Replace this with your own path say /media/odroid/MYUSB/savefolder/output.jpg
ret, frame = cap.read()

cv2.imwrite(savePath,frame)
```

If you want to save the whole video please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317262/opencv-video-saving-in-python)

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

savePath = 'output.avi' #Replace this with your own path say /media/odroid/MYUSB/savefolder/output.avi
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')

out = cv2.VideoWriter(savePath, fourcc, 20.0, (int(cap.get(3)), int(cap.get(4))))

while True:

    newret, newframe = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('orig',newframe)
    out.write(newframe)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF

    if k == 27:
        break

ret, frame = cap.read()

cv2.imwrite(savePath,frame)

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Also, your code has some issues, here is a fixed version of it which should work:

```
path='/media/odroid/MYUSB/savefolder/'
capture_img='/demo/capture.jpg' #it seems path should be demo/capture.jpg
image=cv2.imread(capture_img)
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'resave.jpg'),image)
```