# Does OpenCV VideoWriter use FFmpeg? How does it handle compression or other options?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I'm trying to understand how OpenCV VideoWriter works but I'm a bit confused.

Does it use FFmpeg to write/create videos?  If so, how does it handle compression?

You can specify the FOURCC codec but I don't see any options for compression, H264/H265 CRF value, etc?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998799/specify-compression-quality-in-python-for-opencv-video-object

Comment: use PyAV instead.